# extern NSString *const in cocoapod becomes nil when used in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a cocoapod with some .h and .m files. In one of the .h files, I do the following code, to define a string constant:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const MURDatabaseUpdatedNotification;
extern NSString * const MURDatabaseReadyNotification;

@interface MURDatabaseSingleton : NSObject
...
```

In the according .m file, I declared the constants as follow:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MURDatabaseSingleton.h"

NSString * const MURDatabaseUpdatedNotification = @"MURDatabaseUpdatedNotification";
NSString * const MURDatabaseReadyNotification = @"MURDatabaseReadyNotification";

@interface MURDatabaseSingleton ()
...
```

So far, so good. Inside the .m file, I can fire Notifications with the name using one of the defined strings in a perfect way. 
Outside it, using this as a cocoapod in my app, `MURDatabaseReadyNotification` and `MURDatabaseUpdatedNotification` are suddenly nil. Catching the Notifications shows me that they have been fired using the right name, but the constants are nil.

```
NSLog(@"MURDatabaseReadyNotification: %@", MURDatabaseReadyNotification);
```

I'm struggling for hours on that stupid issue for now, I hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Try defining your constants in seperate files like Constants.h and .m. And nothing else in these files like implementation. And make sure that these files included in application/framework's target.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out, added the .m file to the target but still the same behaviour. Stepping through the debugger and watching MURDatabaseUpdatedNotification's value shows me the correct value within the methods in the library, but as soon as i'm outside, it turns nil. I have added a descriptive screenshot of the function stack.

Comment: "in the library" means the "project" right? I understand that you can reach the values of constants inside the project from all classes, but not from the pod project. Is it true?

Comment: correct, MURDatabaseSingleton is part of a cocoapod that i use in my app. MOWHealthKitStore is within my app's project.

Comment: It is a repetition comment but, you need to define all constants outside of MURDatabaseSingleton class. And include the .h file in your classes. As far as I see from your code and attachment, you declare constants in same file with singleton

Comment: ...still the same. I moved out definition and declaration. there are not interfaces, protocols or other objective c style. I cross checked with another pod i use, Appirater. They define and declare their consts in the same way and they are accessible as expected. What might be interesting, i can (re)define the consts in my app's code. In my understanding, this means, the definition must be somehow private, otherwise the compiler should go weird, isn't it?

Comment: Interesting: I created a new project, included the pod and did a NSLog of the constant. it works. so, it has something to do with some linker or compiler flags i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating into the issue for several hours, I figured out, that the problem was kind of a caching problem. I tried to add another new constant and tried to access it, but the compiler suddenly reported, that this new constant was  not even declared.

I found an outdated build data in **/Users/pgrundner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-**. Even cleaning the project was not updating the old content in this directory. Nevertheless, **deleting the app's directory in DerivedData** was the solution.